# Progressbar при загрузке XML на C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

С progressbarom не получается. Помогите просто без бара чтобы считались цифрами загруженные данные от до 0 до <сколько узлов в xml>
Есть код вывода xml в datagridview:

Как сделать прогрессбар от 0 до вывода?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           try
            {     var dataSet = new DataSet();
                   dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
                   MessageBox.Show("Файл загружен");
          catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        }
```

Comment: progressbar прикрутить не проблема, проблема получить информацию о прогрессе. надеюсь, вы это понимаете.

Comment: я пробовал с циклом for от 0 до 100 и в цикл вставил этот код, так файл сам загружается за 5 секунд, а с циклом нужно ждать 100.
Вот я и не понимаю как найти максимальное значение и выбрать нормальный шаг чтобы загружалось все одинаковое время и прогресс и сам файл. Как же сделать.

Comment: @Андрей, не могли бы Вы подробнее про 5 секунд и 100? Выше правильно сказали (VladD), что информацию о прогрессе сложно получить. Т.к. работаете с XML, который в памяти отображается не известно с какой скоростью, количество тегов наперед наверно не известно, т.е. не свести к задаче "Найти время, зная расстояние от А до Б и среднюю скорость движения автомобиля".

Comment: Реально файл у меня загружается 5 секунд. (порядка 300 основных узлов). Далее я просто нашел в нете код прогресса с циклом от 0 до 100 и для пробы прям в цикл вставил код вывода xml с шагом 1. Прогресс стал работать с шагом в 1 секунду. Я посмотрел на это и понял что файл загрузится из-за прогрессбара за 100 секунд вместо 5 сек. я просто пробовал найденный код.

Comment: Узнать "сколько узлов есть в XML" можно только распарсив весь XML.

Comment: @PashaPash я видел программу в которой сразу показывается 0 из 250 000 записей. и потом пошел парсинг. Естественно я не знаю как и что там реализовано. Как что сделать подскажите

Comment: Вот кажется нашел похожее на английской версии сайта.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099149/how-to-use-progress-bar-during-loading-an-xml-file
Но адаптировать сам я не смогу. Помогите кто может адаптировать к моему случаю DGV, по возможности

Answer (score 2):

Создайте файловый поток и загружайте из него. Тогда процент загрузки можно будет узнать как `100 * fs.Position / fs.Length`, где `fs` - тот самый поток. Ну или можно ничего не вычислять, оставив эту работу прогрес-бару.

Более подробно. Синхронный вариант:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead("file.xml"))
        {
          progressbar.Maximum = 100;
          var length = fs.Length;
          var task = Task.Run(() => dataSet.ReadXml(fs));
          while (!task.Wait(500)) {
            progressbar.Value = (int)(100 * fs.Position / length);
          }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
        MessageBox.Show("Файл загружен");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

Асинхронный вариант:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead("file.xml"))
        {
          progressbar.Maximum = 100;
          var length = fs.Length;
          var task = Task.Run(() => dataSet.ReadXml(fs));
          while (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(500)) != task) {
            progressbar.Value = (int)(100 * fs.Position / length);
          }
          await task;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
        MessageBox.Show("Файл загружен");
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

Comment: Хм. А из какого потока читать `Position`?

Comment: @VladD, из того, из которого загружается DataSet. Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: Эээ... `var task = Task.StartNew(() => dataSet.ReadXml(fs));`: вы читаете данные не в том потоке, в котором создали `fs`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_8 (ну и читаете `Position` не в том потоке, где происходит загрузка).

Comment: Не могу попробовать пример. Ругается на Task и все fs. Что нужно дописать и какие using добавить?

Comment: @Андрей: Попробуйте Alt-Shift-F10.

Comment: @VladD, да, я знаю об этом. Но, во-первых, нигде не написано, что поток нельзя менять - главное чтобы только один поток владел объектом в каждый момент времени. Прибиты гвоздями к создавшему потоку только объекты GUI. Во-вторых, `Position` не меняет состояния объекта - а значит, в худшем случае там будет мусор, но ничего при этом не сломается.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Нууу... В C++ несинхронизироавнный доступ есть UB. Не «прочитается что-то не то», а реальное UB. У вас есть ссылка на то, что в C# не так?

Comment: Ошибка 1 Элемент "Task" не существует в текущем контексте.
Ошибка 2 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "long" в "int". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)

Comment: @Андрей: Попробуйте ещё раз Alt-Shift-F10. Что-то получилось?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Про то, что поток нельзя менять, написано здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_8

Comment: @Андрей, класс Task - это вот этот: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: или ничего не происходит. или появляется окно с ошибкой "запустить последнее успешное или отменить"

Comment: @Андрей, исправил преобразование типов.

Comment: Осталась последняя ошибка в коде номер 1 (синхронный)
Ошибка 1 "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" не содержит определение для "StartNew"
я добавил:
на всякий случай
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

Comment: Блин, гугл меня троллит своей морфологией... `Task.Run`, конечно же, там никогда не было метода `Task.StartNew`...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, доступ к переменным - ошибка пропала. осталась последняя )
Ошибка 1 "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" не содержит определение для "Run"
может какой-то супер using прописать ?

Comment: @Андрей, ну блин, запустите задачу любым другим способом. Прочитайте любой учебник про задачи... А лучше - перейдите на современную версию фреймворка!

Comment: у меня экспресс 2010. Я в нете находил десятки примеров, но 99% из них не запускаются или непонятно куда код вставить. В этом вся беда

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Найдите! Не в контексте async/await? Если да, я исправлю.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Окей, создание объекта в одном потоке и доступ к нему из другого, кажется, поддерживается: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_3 Окей, согласен со всем, кроме доступа к `Position`. Удалю лишние и ошибочные комментарии.

Comment: Установил студию 2015. Ругается в кодах на: Task.run, Task.delay, Task.WhenAny - ошибка одинаковая (Ошибка CS0117 "Task" не содержит определение для "run" и т.п.). Как исправить?

Comment: @Андрей используйте фреймворк 4.5, а не старые

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, да, полез в панель управления виндой - удалил net 4.0 и код заработал. Вот только настроить его не получается. Прогресс загружается на 1/3 в начале выполнения кода, потом все стоит на месте до полного выполнения кода, а потом сразу оставшиеся 2/3 добегают до конца. т.е. реальное выполнение не отражается..Попробовал оба кода

Comment: @Андрей, вам надо было не удалять фреймворк, а изменить настройки проекта...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, ну я восстановил все версии net. Прогресс бар работает все так же двумя рывками

Comment: @Андрей если там именно что два рывка - значит, сама по себе загрузка быстрая, а основное время занимают служебные операции. Поставьте тогда прогресс-бару `progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee` и не мучайтесь.