# Подскажите где в этом коде название столбца или как изменить?

Tags: c#

Привет. Нашел код в нете на c#. Не знаю где название столбца или как изменить. Помогите, а?

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", dataGridView1.Columns[ctr.TabIndex].Name, ctr.Text);
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns[ctr.TabIndex].Name`.

Comment: а прописать мой столбец как? пробую - ругается.

Comment: а как пробуете?

Comment: пишу вот так dataGridView1.Columns[ctr.TabIndex].model, ctr.Text); ошибка: "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn" не содержит определения для "model" и не был найден метод расширения "model", принимающий тип "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). И так ругается dataGridView1.Columns[ctr.model].name

Comment: Вместо `dataGridView1.Columns[ctr.TabIndex].Name` просто пишете название своего столбца (в ковычках).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Control ctr = (Control)sender;
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", [ИМЯ СТОЛБЦА], [ЗНАЧЕНИЕ]);
```

В итоге у вас формируется строка вида "[Имя столбца] LIKE '%[Значение]'" что и подставляется в фильтр дататейбла

Comment: Да. сделал вот так = работает. (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", "model", ctr.Text);

Comment: Блин, вы такие умные )). Подскажите еще по этому вопросу, там всего лишь исправить "поиск без учета порядка слов", остальное работает: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461044/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-datagrid-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-xml

Comment: А можете подсказать по этому вопросу, а то предложенный вариант не работает у меня? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460338/progressbar-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-xml-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c  Сделать бы или счетчик строк при обработке xml или прогресс бар.